# How can I create and activate Customers through the API?

Tags: shopify

As I understand it, creating Customers through the Shopify API gives them a status of 'disabled' until they are invited through the UI. I've seen some hacks around this using mechanize, but is there really no way to do this properly through the API?

Its going to take 9,000 clicks to activate 3,000 customers. Ouch.

Answer (score 0):

or.. one little script using Mechanize. It was made to do the 9000 clicks. Computers are great at automating mundane tasks. You could also probably use Selenium and Javascript. If you are using the API, automating button clicks is probably well within reach in less code than you think.

Comment: Thanks David, I will go with Mechanize if it comes down to it.